# database connection time in postgresql using php

Tags: php, postgresql

I want to find out the maximum no of connections my postgresql server can handle, for which I used Php to connect to my postgresql database.I s there any way in which I can find out the time taken to connect.

This is the code I wrote to connect to postgresql database.

```
for($i=0;$i<1000000000:$i++){
try{
$link=pg_connect("dbname=testdatabase user=xxxx password=xxxxx");

}
catch{
catch(Exception $e) {
  echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
}

}
```

I used

```
 /timing 



select * from pg_stat_activity
```

But I want to know the time it took to connect to the database so many times  when that code was executed.How should I proceed?

Comment: change in `/var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf` `max_connections` to the value you want. also read this http://community.southpawtech.com/content/how-increase-maximum-database-connection

Comment: ok. but I also want to find out the time taken to make so many connections. How should I do that

Comment: Unless you disabled pooling, it's not really connecting at all, it's just reusing the one connection. Also: you should really be using connection pooling, not making new connections each time.

Comment: how fastest you can get to your max_connections value to be exceeded? if it set to 200 with simple script around 5 sec.

Comment: There's no pooling with `pg_connect`, but  `PGSQL_CONNECT_FORCE_NEW` as the second argument is required to actually reopen a connection with the same arguments. And add a `pg_close` in the loop, otherwise `max_connections` will be reached in less than a second. And use `microtime` to count the total time outside of your loop.